# why does my numbers no show up when I run my codes

Tags: java

You’re going to automate the famous song “99 Bottles of XXX on the wall”. You will print the lyrics of ALL 99 verses of the song. Use a loop! If you don’t know the lyrics, look them up with google.

The program should:

- Ask the user for their age
- If the user is 21 or older, ask them if they prefer beer or soda

  a. If they are under 21 OR they prefer soda, then the lyrics are “99 bottles of soda on the wall”

  b. If they are over 21, then it is “99 Bottles of Beer”
- YOU MUST USE A WHILE LOOP and the counter variable must be part of the print statement!
- So the first verse would be:

  *99 bottles of soda on the wall*

  99 bottles of soda

  If one of those bottles should fall off the wall

  …..98 bottles of soda on the wall
- The last verse:

  *1 bottle of soda on the wall*

  1 bottle of soda

  If that lone bottle of soda should fall off the wall

  No bottles of soda on the wall!

So think, what do you need to add to your loop to print the last verse with the slightly different lyrics?

// here is my code. When I run it the number of bottles start from 12, not 99
How do I fix this??

```
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

           int age, beverage;


           System.out.println("Please type in your age");
           age = user.nextInt();

           user.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Would you like soda or beer? soda=1 beer=2");
           beverage = user.nextInt();

        if(age<21 || beverage==1)
           {
           int bottles = 99;
            while( 1< bottles){
                System.out.println(bottles+" of soda on the wall");
                System.out.println(bottles+" bottles of soda");
                System.out.println("If one of those bottles should fall off the wall");
                bottles--;
                System.out.println("..."+bottles+" bottles of soda on the wall");
            if(bottles==1){
                System.out.println(bottles+" of soda on the wall");
                System.out.println(bottles+" bottles of soda");
                System.out.println("If that lone bottle of soda should fall off the wall");
                System.out.println("No bottles of soda on the wall");
            }
        }
    }
        if(age>=21 && beverage == 2)
        {
            int bottles=99;
            while(1< bottles){
                System.out.println(bottles+" of beer on the wall");
                System.out.println(bottles+" bottles of beer");
                System.out.println("If one of those bottles should fall off the wall");
                bottles--;
                System.out.println("..."+bottles+" bottles of beer on the wall");
            if(bottles==1){
                System.out.println(bottles+" of beer on the wall");
                System.out.println(bottles+" bottles of beer");
                System.out.println("If that lone bottle of beer should fall off the wall");
                System.out.println("No bottles of beer on the wall");
            }
        }
    }

        }
    }
```

Comment: try changing it from `while(1<bottles)` to `while(1<=bottles)`

Comment: There are issues in the way you are coding. Recommend posting this code on codereview.stackexchange.com if you want to learn from experienced programmers.

Comment: No point in looping until 1 < bottles and checking the condition every cycle, loop until it's 2 (including) and print the last line at the end.

Comment: Rather than duplicating all the `println` statements just to say "beer" instead of "soda", you can put that one word into a `String` variable and print the messages based on that variable: `bottles + " of " + beverage + " on the wall"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code *does* start printing with 99 bottles. If you only see the last 12 bottles, there's an issue with your output console. Try scrolling further up, or try with a different console, or try redirecting it to a file (add " > output.txt" to your command line call and then check the content of ouput.txt).

Comment: This is a comment, not a full-proof answer!